# Column <x> has dtype object, cannot use method 'nsmallest' with this dtype

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Any query I try on my table complains that

```
Column 'time' has dtype object, cannot use method 'nsmallest' with this dtype
```

However, when I look at the table source that I queried, the schema reports types of long. In this case, I am querying Treasure Data.

How then do I sort my dataframe by a column value and the the one with the least?

Comment: What does `df.dtypes` report for that column? is it object?

Comment: maybe `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` would help.

Comment: df.dtypes says every single column is an object, however, the source of the data says that every single column is a string or a long.

Answer (score 2):

You sort it by:

```
df.sort_values(['time'], inplace=True)
```

If you use:

```
df['time'].sort_values(ascending=True).head(n)
```

You should get the first n smallest values as well.